# How to "break" a bootstrap layout then printing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I'd like to be able to print some stickers. 
But when I want to print the view, some of the bootstrap cards used to display each dataset are cut between two pages.

Here is my code (twig) :

```
{% block moteurs_body %}
    <p></p>
    {% set boucle = 6 %}

    <div class="container">

        {% for moteur in moteurs %}
            {% if (loop.index % (6*6) == 0) and not loop.first %}<div class="newPage"></div>{% endif %}
            {% if loop.first %}
                <div class="row">
            {% endif %}

            {% if boucle == 0 %}
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                {% set boucle = 6 %}
            {% endif %}
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../../{{ moteur.urlQRCode }}" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        {{ moteur.numeroMoteur }}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% set boucle = (boucle - 1) %}

        {% if loop.last %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the client side HTML (only a few elements where the problem occurs, there are a lot of stickers...)

```
    <div id="header" class=" text-center">
    <h5>Liste des certificats | <span class="badge badge-secondary">108 moteurs 250kg</span></h5>
    <h6 class="success">utilisez la fonction "imprimer" de votre navigateur pour imprimer au format A4</h6>
</div>

<p></p>

<div class="container">


                        <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L0442MQ.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L0442MQ
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L0840PF.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L0840PF
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L0854PF.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L0854PF
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L0963RQ.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L0963RQ
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L2650SN.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L2650SN
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m1000/L2662SN.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L2662SN
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                        </div>
            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L2740RN.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L2740RN
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3561TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3561TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3562TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3562TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3563TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3563TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3564TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3564TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3566TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3566TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                        </div>
            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3567TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3567TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3568TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3568TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3569TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3569TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3570TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3570TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L3665TK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L3665TK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L4397SR.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L4397SR
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                        </div>
            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/L4401SR.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        L4401SR
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/NL1149WC.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        NL1149WC
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/NL2722UK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        NL2722UK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/NL2726UK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        NL2726UK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/NL3482UK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        NL3482UK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/NL3493UK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        NL3493UK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                        </div>
            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/NL3494UK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        NL3494UK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/NL5391UJ.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        NL5391UJ
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m500/NL5396UJ.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        NL5396UJ
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/NL5461UK.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        NL5461UK
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/SS2497TP.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        SS2497TP
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/SS2499TP.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        SS2499TP
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                        </div>
            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/SS3465SR.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        SS3465SR
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/SS3466SR.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        SS3466SR
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/SS3472SR.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        SS3472SR
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/SS3475SR.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        SS3475SR
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/SS3476SR.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        SS3476SR
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


                                                <div class="newPage"></div>

                    <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../..//images/qrcodes/m250/SS3477SR.png" alt="Mince, pas d'image...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        SS3477SR
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is part of my css:

```
.newPage {
    display: block;
    break-before:always;
}
```

And what I don't want :

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xbTj.jpg)

I'd like to have 36 stickers per page so I tried to count the loops to insert a .newPage css rule each 36 stickers, but no success. 
Does someone have an ideas to go to a new page each 36 dataset ?

Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: Include the actual HTML in your question. stuff on the server side doesn't tell us what the display looks like.

Comment: Hi miken82, Thanks for your answer. I added the html code plus an image so you can "see" what I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a Chrome issue, a little documented on the web. 
I tried my code on Safari, and it's OK.

If someone knows how to fix my code in order to work on Chrome, I take it ! But for the moment I'll run it on Safari.

Thanks for your help